# If é executado mesmo com a condição sendo falsa

Tags: c

Tenho um trecho de uma função com o seguinte codigo:

```
printf("caminho: %d\n", t);
printf("min: %d\n", min);
if( min >= t && t != -1);
{
    printf("oi\n");
    min = t;
    printf("min: %d\n",min);
}
```

e como resultado tenho:

> caminho: 2
>
> min: 1
>
> oi
>
> min: 2

A linha que imprime "oi" é executada, mesmo com a condicional devendo ser falsa.

Alguém pode me dizer como isso pode acontecer?

Comment: Poste o código mais completo, ao menos o pedaço onde as variáveis são declaradas. Melhor ainda, poste um exemplo mínimo e compilável que reproduza o problema.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Você tem um ponto-e-vírgula na frente da condição do seu `if`:

```
if( min >= t && t != -1);
```

Independente do resultado, nada vai acontecer.

Em seguida, você tem um bloco solto:

```
{
    printf("oi\n");    
    min = t;
    printf("min: %d\n",min);
}
```

Que vai ser executado de todo jeito.